# What is the path to ws?

Tags: heroku, websockets

I'm trying to host a websocket server on my heroku app. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I upload it to Heroku, i only get 404 errors, you can try by yourself : wss://ethyme-api.herokuapp.com/ 
So what is the path to the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Your WS path looks good to me it may an issue on the server side.

Here's how I build the WS URL on the client side to run on local and Heroku:

```js
const wsUrl = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' 
                   ? 'ws://' 
                   : 'wss://') 
               + window.location.host;
```

Comment: mh I can't do this, my api isnt hosted on the same domain as my website. Here is how I create the websocket server : `const server = http.createServer(app); /* express app */
        const wss = new Server({ server }); /* from ws */`
and then `const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) | 8000;    server.listen(port, () => console.log(\`Serveur WebSocket prêt sur le port ${(server['address']() as any).port}\`))`

Comment: I don't think that your WS server is running. You should call the WebSocket `Server` constructor AFTER listening with Express.

Comment: mmm this doesnt change anything

Comment: are the logs normal ? 
`2020-02-19T18:27:30.261142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ethyme-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d6c0e965-ca39-4b76-bfd8-6aa5c35f377b fwd="77.204.130.110" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=420 protocol=https`